# Find out where information comes form

Tags: ruby

I'm piecing together how the rspec-core gem works and I've come across a brick wall. This is inside the `Example` class:

```
def description
   description = if metadata[:description].to_s.empty?
                    location_description
                  else
                    metadata[:description]
                  end

    RSpec.configuration.format_docstrings_block.call(description)
end
```

I'm finding it impossible to find out where the hash inside `metadata` actually comes from.

I've tried ctags - it directed me towards `ExampleGroup#metadata` which is a method that returns a hash pertaining to groups; it's not the same hash that's inside the `metadata` call in the example. Disappointed with ctags - I was expecting the speed by which I piece together how gems work to experience a quantum leap if ctags worked as advertised.

How is anyone supposed to find out where the information returned by a call comes from?

Personally I find it pretty weird, inside [the example class](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/example.rb) there is no `def metadata` nor `metadata = {}` and yet there the metadata call sits within `#description`, returning a hash. There is a `attr_reader :metadata`, but that's "outgoing". That's if something outside the class wants to access an Example instance' metadata (even though it doesn't contain a metadata method but whatever); attr_reader has nothing to do with setting. So I guess the only explanation is that `metadata` is a method defined in some other class? Be awesome if ctags could actually do its job and direct me to said method.

Is something like this fictional `where_is_it`method possible? This would be brilliant:

```
def description
     where_is_it metadata #=> rspec-core/lib/some_support_class.rb:132
end
```

Comment: I think ruby mine allows you to trace code back to where it was instantiated. Looking at the rspec code it seems to get it from `example_group.rb`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `p method(:metadata).source_location` in a place where this method is accessible (i.e. callable). That should give you an array with path and line number, like this:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
[1] pry(main)> app.method(:get).source_location
=> ["/Users/alexey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@pgm-rails2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb", 31]
```

Comment: That tells me the origin of `metadata` is `attr_reader :metadata`, which doesn't make sense to me. Could you explain?